# Maven credentials in gitlab CI

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab CI to deploy artifacts to my team's maven repository and I'm having difficulty to setup the maven credentials.

I don't want to put them on the settings.xml file since the CI runner is used by other teams with different repositories and I'd like to keep our repository clean from other artifacts.

How can I do it differently? I was thinking of using maven arguments or the POM file along with CI variables.

Comment: It seems you already have the answer, have you tried the solutions you were thinking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you wrote you can use variable defined in CI.

Next you can use environment variable in settings.xml, eg:

```
<settings>
    ...
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>yourId</id>
            <username>${env.CI_MVN_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.CI_MVN_PASSWORD}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    ...
</settings>
```

According to example you can use common settings.xml and each team will define own maven credentials.